# Extruding a shape into 3D geometry in monogame/Xna

Tags: javascript, c#, 3d, xna, monogame

I have previously done a project of building a 3D environment that allow user to draw a shape and then extrude it into a 3D geometry (e.g. a circle into a cylinder) using a javascript library Three.js with a function called ExtrudeGeometry().

currently I am building a similar program but on mobile platform using Xamarin and monogame/Xna. Being able to extrude a shape into 3D geometry does make many thing much more easier, however, so far I haven't found a similar function that provides similar functionality. Is there a counterpart of ExtrudeGeometry in Three.js in monogame/Xna? or an alternative way to accomplish same result.